# Does SqlCommand.ExecuteReader / SqlDataReader.Read swallow exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, exception, ado.net

Consider the following code:

```
namespace SqlExceptionTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var sql =
    @"BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1;
    THROW 50000, 'An error occured.', 1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     THROW
END CATCH
";

                using (var cnn = new SqlConnection("<totally valid connection string>"))
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                {
                    cnn.Open();

                    using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            while (r.Read())
                            {
                                // do something
                            }
                        } while (r.NextResult());

                        r.Close();
                    }

                    cnn.Close();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Code executed without any issues.");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception was raised");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I know the T-Sql code here make no sense, it's only for demonstrations purposes.)

I would have expected the code above to throw an `SqlException` instance, but appearantly it does not. Instead, the `while` block loops normally up to the end, the connection closes and the program ends. I tried compiling on framework v2 to 4.6 and got the same result, every time.

Do I have a way, in .NET only (no alteration of the T-Sql code), to use a `SqlDataReader` *and* to know that an error occured *after* the `SELECT` statement ended? Or is it forever lost in ADO.NET's mechanisms?

Comment: Off-topic hint #1: C# supports multi-line string literals: use `@"..."` (which can include line breaks) instead of a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Off-topic hint #2: Put a `using` block around your data reader `r`.

Comment: @stakx Ack, I indeed missed that last `using` block. :p Thanks, updated!

Comment: @stakx: actually not off-topic at all. Adding an using and disposing the reader *before* closing the connection would consume the exception message and raise it in C#. I think.

Comment: @Remus: No, `using` won't trigger the SQL error. It's just good practice to explicitly dispose `IDisposable` components (even when `.Close()` might already have that effect, but that is not self-evident).

Comment: Off-topic hint #3: If you have `using {}` blocks, you do not need to call `Close()` or `Dispose()` on that object, the closing bracket does that for you.

Comment: @LarsTech Yeah I know, I just hoped that the code would throw an exception right on explicitely calling `Close` method. No luck though. :s

Comment: Using ExecuteNonQuery will trigger an SqlException with the expected message in C#

Comment: @Steve True, I tested it myself before posting. I wanted to know if it was just the reader or every single call to the server.

Comment: Just pondering whether it is an optimization due to `System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow`.

Comment: @HABO Hey, that's it! I removed the argument and suddently the code crashes as expected!

Comment: Yup. It took a few minutes for me to confirm it using SS2008R2 and `RaIsError`. I took the liberty of posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Crono +1 for your very keen question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying `System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow` allows the result set to be read without a subsequent exception being thrown in the application.  `System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleResult` provides the same *optimization*.

Comment: Must be because the optimization makes ADO.NET stop listening to any more Sql Server messages as soon as it's done reading the one row / result it was told to. Thus it can't be made aware of the error occuring later on. Makes sense.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Granted, I'm back in the dark ages of VS2010 and SS2008R2, but I am running the code. The behavior is even stranger when the query is changed to `SELECT 1 / 0 AS X;` and the application does `Console.WriteLine((int)r["X"]);` in the innermost loop. No exception and no row returned with either of the troublesome `CommandBehavior` options.

Comment: @HABO You are right and I got confused about that behavior. So I will delete the post to not mislead other users while it has some useful facts. it seems more research about it is needed. Anyway I thank you and Crono for this so useful talk, at least for me:)